# Using Firebase Phone Authentication not getting notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm currently implementing firebase phone Authentication, and can successfully implement the phone authentication using the firebase UI without swizzling, but from my research it seems that implementing firebase phone authentication without swizzling requires the user to allow notifications. I know that firebase sends a silent notification that does not need to be approved through allowing notifications but it seems the only way to get that notification without swizzling is to ask the user to allow notification. Does anyone know how or if its possible to do this without swizzling and without asking the user for notification permissions?

I have added to push notification certificates to firebase, and have added all the needed function listed in the firebase phone ui docs.

Without asking the user for to allow notifications this function listed from the phone auth docs does not get called (the user also has to select allow)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  // Pass device token to auth
  Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd)

  // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
  // ...
}
```

If this functions is not called the setAPNSToken is not set, I will not get the silent notification to continue with phone auth, and I will get the generic error

> Authentication error: There seems to be a problem with your project's
>   Firebase phone number authentication set-up, please make sure to
>   follow the instructions found at
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went ahead and disabled [method swizzling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in) as stated in the Firebase docs and then implemented all the required methods, the solution was that I needed to go the **Capabilities** of the app and then make sure **Background Modes** as well as **Push Notifications** (this was already enabled) were enabled. Then under **Background Modes** I had to enable **Remote notifications**.

Then I had to delete the app from my device and reinstall. This solved my issue and called the necessary functions for registering for notifications.

Comment: Hey Mark, you saved my day here! After trying *a lot* of crazy things, I think your hint of enabling *Background Modes* really did the trick for me. Cheers from Rio ;)

Comment: Had same issue, wonder why this is not part of their docs 